# How to make giant explosion with one command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to know if you can make giant explosions via creeper, TNT, or anything. and I want it to be a synchronized explosion. Tell me the code and the biggest possible explosion you can make in Vanilla with command blocks or as a command

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 8):

Creepers have an `ExplosionRadius` tag to determine the size of the explosion. Because it's a Byte tag, it has a maximum of 127:

```
/summon Creeper ~ ~1 ~ {ExplosionRadius:127}
```

Ghasts have an `ExplosionPower` Integer tag, meaning the maximum value is 2,147,483,647 (which will most certainly crash your game when attempting to use it):

```
/summon Ghast ~ ~1 ~ {ExplosionPower:2147483647}
```

The Fireball entity also has an `ExplosionPower` Integer tag:

```
/summon Fireball ~ ~1 ~ {ExplosionPower:2147483647}
```

MinecartTNT, PrimedTnt, and EnderCrystal entities do not have any tags to determine the radius of their explosion.

You can find NBT data for entities [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format).

And general info on the NBT format (including minimum/maximum values) [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nbt_format).

Comment: I'd like to add that normally you shouldn't experiment with `ExplosionPower` higher than 150.

Answer (score 0):

you can do `/effect @e[type=creeper] invisibility 2555 255` then                                                                `/execute @e[type=tnt]~ ~ ~ summon Creeper ~ ~1 ~ {ExplosionRadius:127}` in 2 command blocks